# Handling memory exhausted in Windows Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, out-of-memory

My application can use a lot of memory and I want to be able to handle running out of memory gracefully. So I do this:

```
bool Application::notify( QObject* receiver, QEvent* event )
{
    bool done = true;
    try
    {
        done = QApplication::notify( receiver, event );
    }
    catch ( std::bad_alloc& ex )
    {
        releaseMemory();
        qWarning() << "bad_alloc exception: " << ex.what();
        m_outOfMemoryDlg->exec();
        exit( 1 );
    }
    catch ( const std::exception& ex )
    {
        releaseMemory();
        qWarning() << "exception: " << ex.what();
        criticalMessage( nullptr, QString( "%1 has to close due to an exception. Please contact support." ).arg( APP_NAME ) );
        exit( 2 );
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        releaseMemory();
        qWarning() << "exception";
        criticalMessage( nullptr, QString( "%1 has to close. Please contact support." ).arg( APP_NAME ) );
        exit( 3 );
    }
    return done;
}
```

Where m_outOfMemoryDlg is a QDialog with a helpful message I create and hide at startup. This all works fine on macOS. I get a std::bad_alloc exception, the QDialog appears and the program shuts gracefully. But on Windows the whole OS just locks. The screen is frozen and I have to power off and back on to make it responsive.

In my .pro file I added:

```
CONFIG += exceptions

win32 {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_EXCEPTIONS_ON = /EHa
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_STL_ON = /EHa
}
```

I also added:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <new.h>
LONG WINAPI
exceptionFilter( struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* exceptionInfo )
{
    if ( exceptionInfo )
    {
        EXCEPTION_RECORD* er = exceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord;
        if ( er )
        {
            qWarning() << "Windows exception: " << er->ExceptionCode;
        }
    }
    exit( 4 );
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int outOfMemory( size_t )
{
    qWarning() << "Out of memory";
    exit( 5 );
    return 0;
}
#endif

Application::Application( int& argc, char** argv )
: QApplication( argc, argv )
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter( exceptionFilter );
    _set_new_handler( outOfMemory );
#endif
...
}
```

As per https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cplusplus . Still no luck. Any ideas?

I am using Qt 5.15.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: You may never get a `std::bad_alloc& ex` as the OS may try to use many GBs of your disk as swap causing the OS to slow to a crawl. It will be still working but not very useful when the GUI becomes totally unresponsive.

Comment: I don't think SEH will help either because there is no exception. The OS is allowing your application to consume an increasingly large amount of an expanding page file slowing the OS to a crawl. With this said both of these comments are about 64 bit applications. For 32 bit applications you can easily run out of address space and in that you should get a bad_alloc

Comment: Is there a way to detect when you reach, say, 50% of the available virtual memory?

Comment: There are windows specific ways using winapi. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could check how much virtual memory is left on a timer. Being able to catch an exception would be much cleaner though.

Comment: My advice is to wait and see if anyone has more input. While I used to worry about this 20 years ago in 32 bit all the time since I switched to x64 my applications rarely are using more than 16GB so its not really a large concern for my work as a medical imaging researcher.

Comment: I hear you. It isn't normally an issue with 64 bit systems. However this is an ETL app and can be very memory hungry. And customers won't be happy about it locking or crashing their PC!